# Is this a valid property for Riemann Sums

Tags: riemann-sum

$R$ is a refinement of $Q$

then

$$U(R, f) − L(R, f) ≤ U(Q, f) − L(Q, f)$$

Comment: Assuming these are upper and lower sums, yes, that's correct. This is one of the key properties in the "Darboux development" of Riemann integration.

Comment: You can see that by the monotony of the upper and lower bounds. The upper bound is non increasing and the upper bound is non decreasing under refinement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is a refinement of $Q$ then $U(R,f) \leq U(Q,f)$ and $L(Q,f) \leq L(R,f).$

Proof:

Let $Q = \{a = x_0 ,...,x_{i-1},x_i,...,x_n=b\}$. WLOG, suppose $R = \{a=x_0,...x_{i-1},z,x_i,...,x_n = b\}$.

By definition, $U(Q,f) = \sum_{k=1}^nM_k\Delta x_k$, where $M_k$ and $\Delta x_k$ have the usual definitions.

Also, $U(R,f) = \sum_{k=1}^{i-1}M_k\Delta x_k + M_{z}^1(z - x_{i-1}) +M_{z}^{2}(x_i -z) +\sum_{k=i+1}^nM_k\Delta x_k$, where $M_{z}^1 = sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},z]}f(x)$ and $M_z^2 = sup_{x\in [z,x_i]}f(x)$.

It is easy to see that $M_i\Delta x_i \geq M_z^1(z-x_{i-1})+M_z^2(x_i-z)$, so $U(R,f)\leq U(Q,f)$.

A somewhat similar argument can be made for the lower sums. QED.

Your statement is a direct consequence of these inequalities.